# ActionBarSherlock - Weird color underneath

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been working with the libraries ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu. It has been working pretty well, but I noticed a weird color right under the ActionBar. It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMBZA.jpg

My background color is #E7E7E7, and I don't know where this #DEDFDE comes from. I noticed the color in the SlidingMenu Example application ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example ) and I really don't like it. I'm not sure what code to post so there is my setup of the SlidingMenu

```
sm = new SlidingMenu(this);
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
sm.setFadeEnabled(false);
sm.setBehindScrollScale(0.0f);
sm.setFadeEnabled(true);
sm.setFadeDegree(0.5f);
sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
SlidingMenu.attachSlidingMenu(this, sm, true);
sm.setMenu(R.layout.lists_frame);
```

My ActionBar Java setup

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.actionbar_lists);
mActionBar.setTitle("Choose a list");
```

And my styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style> 
 <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0099ff</item>
    <item name="background">#ff0099ff</item>
</style>
```

I would of course like to get rid of it, and I tried searching but without an answer. Hope you guys can help, and if you need any other code snippets, please say so.

It should also be said that if I use

```
SlidingMenu.attachSlidingMenu(this, sm, false);
```

the color also appears on the view below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is caused by the shadow that is often placed under the action bar. The shadow is defined in the theme in `android:windowContentOverlay` item (`windowContentOverlay` for `ActionBarSherlock`).

`ActionBarSherlock` has it defined by default for `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`.

If you want to get rid of id, just cancel it in the theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```